# Starcraft 2 API

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there an SC2 API where I can pull buildings, units, and skills information? I know there's one right now heavily used for AI but I registered and browsed their endpoints and saw nothing for the kind of information I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unit types, there is ObservationInterface::[GetUnitTypeData](https://github.com/Blizzard/s2client-api/search?q=UnitTypes&unscoped_q=UnitTypes)() which, as far as I saw when browsing the code, should return information on all unit types. I think buildings, in this context, are just another type of unit.

For Abilities, there is ObservationInterface::[GetAbilityData](https://github.com/Blizzard/s2client-api/search?q=abilities&unscoped_q=abilities)()